# How to insert a variable in NSString

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to insert a variable (imageName) in a string but no luck so far.

```
NSString *imageName= @"image.jpg";

NSString *newString = @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"**image.jpg**\"\r\n";
```

Here in the above string, I want to pass a variable which will replace the image name (in bold letters).

Comment: Well, you can either substring the containing string to break it into prefix and suffix parts, then concatenate the parts together, or you can use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n":imageName]`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",imageName];
```

Comment: It's better to add some explanation to the code ;)

Comment: Actually, don't know how to explanation this :D. It's so obvious to use that. I just post a quick answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Try append the string with `stringWithFormat`. Eg:

`NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"...filename=%@", imageName];`